# Typescript doesn't recognize property type

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Even though I declared type for activeNumber(), this.activeIndex + 1 is underlined with red and VS code is displaying "Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '(() => any) | ComputedOptions' and 'number'." How is this possible? What am I missing?

```
import Vue from 'vue';

interface DataInterface {
  questions: [];
  results: [];
  activeIndex: number;
}

const Component = Vue.extend({
  props: {
    dataSrc: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  },

  data(): DataInterface {
    return {
      questions: [],
      results: [],
      activeIndex: 0
    };
  },

  computed: {
    activeNumber(): number {
      return this.activeIndex + 1;
    }
})    
export default Component;
```

Comment: Sometimes VS code does give error. Opening and closing it mostly solves. Are you also getting this issue while compiling your project?

Also, this is not the syntax to assign a value
`activeIndex: 0` . The correct syntax is `activeIndex= 0`

Comment: try initializing activeIndex instead of only declaring.

Comment: @AshishDeora Reopening it didn't solve it unfortunately. I'm also getting an error at compiling, although it's not specifically mentioning the issue I described. When I have the script in JS and remove the type declaration it does compile.

Comment: `activeIndex: 0` - this is the error. make it `activeIndex = 0`

Comment: Within the DataInterface object? That would be invalid syntax.

Comment: I copy pasted your code to a typescript + vue project. Typings were correct for me.

Comment: @AJT82 Hmm weird, but good to know. I'm gonna check it out with a colleague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the error disappeared after rebooting my computer a couple of times, like Ashish Deora suggested in the comments. My colleague suggested that you can also restart the Typescript server in VS code. This option appears when you ctrl+shift+P and search for 'typescript'. That's much quicker than a reboot.